# case insensitive uniqueness - how to update against the current record, regardless of case?

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

I am using Hasura on top of Postgres to store companies and other information. The source data has the same spelling of records, but in differing cases - for example:

| name | country |
| --- | --- |
| Reckitt Benckiser (Aust) Pty Ltd | US |
| RECKITT BENCKISER (AUST) PTY LTD | AU |

I have an index on the name of the company:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_company_unique_idx on company (LOWER(name));
```

When I "upsert" the second record, it throws a uniqueness error, so the index is working correctly. However what I want is for the second record to realise the first record is the same thing, and update the country to AU. If I don't have the index, I get two records for the same entity, in differing cases.

I don't want to store everything in upper or lower case, but am happy for it to take whatever case the first record that was inserted is.

How can I make the upsert process case agnostic?

Comment: please provide your SQLcode that you have problem with .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify what version of Postgres you are running, but if it is 12 or above you can add a virtual (generated) column, then put a unique constraint on that column. See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e22c14d41914c26409bfcea04cdad8b8):

```
alter table table_name add v_company_name text generated always as ( lower(company_name) ) stored;
alter table table_name add constraint company_name_bk unique (v_company_name);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [case insensitive collation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59168841/6464308) or the `citext` extension for the table column and use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` with a normal unique constraint on the column.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the collation as from what I can see `citext` calls a `lower()` every time it is called and I'd like to keep things as efficient as possible

Comment: Of course you will have to pay a price for case insensitive search, since you can no longer use binary comparison.